# Inner Join and Update with SQL Server & PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join

I am trying to update two tables (REQUISITION & STOCK) and subtract two column from both the table by using inner join on SQL Server. I've tried this and it doesn't work out.

```
    <?php
    $tsql = "UPDATE [MRS].[dbo].[REQUISITION] A
             INNER JOIN [MRS].[dbo].[STOCK] B
             ON B.StockId = A.StockId 
             SET A.RequestStatus = 'APPROVED', 
                 A.ApprovedDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
                 GETDATE(),103), 
                 B.StockQuantity = B.StockQuantity - A.RequestQuantity
             WHERE RequestId = '$_GET[RequestId]'";

    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, array(), 
              array ("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));    

    header('Location:approval.php');
 ?>
```

Comment: is this command is firing directly in SQL SERVER SSMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update multiple tables inside single `UPDATE` statement. The only way to do it is to execute two separate `UPDATE` statements inside a single transaction

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE A
SET A.RequestStatus = 'APPROVED', 
    A.ApprovedDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),103)
FROM [MRS].[dbo].[REQUISITION] A
WHERE RequestId = $_GET[RequestId]

UPDATE B
SET B.StockQuantity = B.StockQuantity - A.RequestQuantity
FROM [MRS].[dbo].[REQUISITION] A
INNER JOIN [MRS].[dbo].[STOCK] B ON B.StockId = A.StockId 
WHERE RequestId = $_GET[RequestId]

COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1):

`Update from` syntax is wrong. It should be something like this. You cannot do two updates in a single statement.  Need to keep the update statement in a single transaction and commit the changes only when both update are successful

```
Begin TRAN

UPDATE A
SET    A.RequestStatus = 'APPROVED',
       A.ApprovedDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Getdate(), 103)
FROM   [MRS].[dbo].[REQUISITION] A
       INNER JOIN [MRS].[dbo].[STOCK] B
               ON B.StockId = A.StockId
 WHERE RequestId = $_GET[RequestId]

UPDATE B
SET    B.StockQuantity = B.StockQuantity - A.RequestQuantity
FROM   [MRS].[dbo].[REQUISITION] A
       INNER JOIN [MRS].[dbo].[STOCK] B
               ON B.StockId = A.StockId
 WHERE RequestId = $_GET[RequestId]

COMMIT
```

Comment: you can't update multiple tables in the one UPDATE statement (in MSSQL)

Comment: @Andrey - yes u are right i didn't check that alias properly.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
" ... WHERE RequestId = '$_GET[RequestId]'";
```

To:

```
" ... WHERE RequestId = $_GET[RequestId]";
```

Answer (score 0):

i think Your Update Statement gives error

```
UPDATE A SET A.RequestStatus = 'APPROVED', 
                 A.ApprovedDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103), 
                 A.StockQuantity = B.StockQuantity - A.RequestQuantity
from [MRS].[dbo].[STOCK] B 
JOIN [MRS].[dbo].[REQUISITION] A
ON B.StockId = A.StockId 
WHERE RequestId=Your_request_ID
```

Comment: RequestStatus, ApprovedDate and StockQuantity fields are located in `different` tables - your query is wrong

Comment: @Andrey it will be better if Questioner Provides table structure

Comment: it is undoubtedly true :)